# Windows 7: how to set it to notify me by email of important issues (power loss/UPS, critical system events, etc.)?

Tags: windows-7

I'm new to Windows, having inherited a Win7 machine (which needs to stay Win7 due to custom drivers/hardware it has). How can I set it to send me notifications of important events (system problems, power loss/UPS kicks on, etc.) via email?

Answer (score 0):

1 Open the event viewer

2 select the event you want to be notified

3 In the actions pane select **Attach Task To This Event...** and follow the wizard.

Comment: so the event has to have already occurred (in order to be found in the event viewer, I need to pull the plug of the UPS and let it generate an event on the Win7 system)?

Comment: I'm looking in the event viewer, where would I see a UPS power event?